# Неудачные попытки конвертировать таблицы из MyISAM в InnoDB

Tags: innodb, myisam, mysql

Есть БД MySQL, все таблицы в ней сейчас на движке MyISAM. Пытаюсь выполнить такой SQL запрос в HeidiSQL:

```
ALTER TABLE basket ENGINE = InnoDB;
/* 8 rows affected, 0 rows found. Duration for 1 query: 0,141 sec. */
```

Но таблица после выполнения этого запроса все равно остается в MyISAM. Если же залезть в настройки, то HeidiSQL, а также и PHPMyAdmin, предлагает только такие варианты:

> ```
> MyISAM
> CSV
> MRG_MyISAM
> BLACKHOLE
> ARCHIVE
> MEMORY
> ```

Почему так происходит? Почему я не могу конвертировать таблицы в InnoDB? Полнотекстовых индексов нет!!

Comment: Неужели ни у кого нет даже предположений почему так происходит?

Comment: можно глянуть где это находиться что то вообще не вериться?

Comment: Утром сделаю скриншоты и выложу, потому что сейчас нет доступа к тому компьютеру где находится БД.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вероятнее всего, вы используете некую сборку, типа xampp. Уже сталкивался с тем, что в подобных сборках любят урезать функционал MySQL, в частности, удалять "ненужные" движки. Учитывая выборку, движок InnoDB просто удален. Чтобы он все же был, установите [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) самостоятельно. :)

**UPD >** Исправить можно убрав из конфигурационного файла MySQL директиву **skip-innodb**

Comment: Посмотри список доступных движков:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-engines.html
>SHOW STORAGE ENGINES;

Comment: Собственно, человек пользуется HeidySQL, который и выдает список движков, основываясь на этой команде.